# How to add powershell autocomplete like POSH Git

Tags: git, powershell, posh-git

I'm using POSH git for powershell and can do for example

```
git checkout mini<tab>
```

and I get

```
git checkout minidisk
```

I'd like to create a alias **gco** for **git checkout** to do

```
gco mini<tab>
```

to get

```
gco minidisk
```

Is it possible to forward the tab completion to the POSH git handler?

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing as "git handler". The only thing that posh-git shell is doing is replacing default TabExpansion function with own implementation.

You need to modify their implementation to get behavior you want.

If you want to modify it, just run this command within posh-git shell:

```
notepad (Get-Command TabExpansion).ScriptBlock.File
```

You can replace notepad with your editor of choice.

**EDIT**

There are few ways you can do it in this particular case. With all the complexity in this implementation though I would not invest too much time, I would just try to convince tab function that you actually used 'git checkout':

```
function TabExpansion($line, $lastWord) {
   $line = $line -replace '^gco ', 'git checkout '
   # rest of the function as it is...
```

BTW: there is no way to create alias like that in PowerShell: aliases in PowerShell can replace command, not command + arguments (for latter you will need to define function).

Comment: Ok. That's interesting but it's not clear exactly how I would edit that file to add a single tab expansion for __gco__ to behave like __git commit__

Comment: Modified answer with one possible (and probably most straight-forward) method of achieving this goal.

Comment: I found a better non intrusive way to do this using the PowerTab extension. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23623543/158285

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way to add your own tab expansion hooks via the [PowerTab](https://github.com/jasonmarcher/PowerTab/blob/master/Docs/Development/Handlers.md) powershell plugin. Once you have PowerTab installed. ( You can do this via chocolately using an admin privilege shell) then create the following in your powershell profile

```
# Load posh-git example profile
. 'C:\tools\poshgit\dahlbyk-posh-git-c481e5b\profile.example.ps1'


# Create a function for registering alias's that support tab expansion
function Register-TabExpansion-Alias([string]$alias, [string]$expansion) {

    Invoke-Expression "function global:$alias { $expansion `$args }"

    Register-TabExpansion -Name $alias -Type Command {
        param($Context, [ref]$TabExpansionHasOutput, [ref]$QuoteSpaces) 

        $Argument = $Context.Argument
        if ( $Argument -notlike '^\$' ){
            $TabExpansionHasoutput.Value = $true 
            TabExpansion "$expansion $Argument"
        }
    }.GetNewClosure()
}

Register-TabExpansion-Alias "gco" "git checkout"
Register-TabExpansion-Alias "grb" "git rebase"
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use git aliases e.g.

```
git config --global alias.co checkout
```

Now you can use:

```
git co develop
```

Not quite a short as `gco` but other gitters are likely to recognize `git co` over `gco`.